# how to convert text with html tag into DOM in express nodejs bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text output from DB with formatted with HTML tags.

```
<p>Some text</p><ul><li>some 1</li></ul>
```

Now In the browser when I display the result. the HTML tags not converted into DOM.
I tried to replace <> with < > Still not working.

I am using nodejs in back and using bootstrap in view

Comment: How are you displaying the result? When you receive back the HTML what are you doing with it?

Comment: You're probably sending response content type as text and not as HTML.

Comment: Can we see how you print your html ?

Comment: I got the JSON from MongoDB, and sent it through response, and then in view showing the JSON from response. using handlebars in view

Comment: {{#if card.description}}
   <div class="row marketing text-center">
    <p>
     {{card.description}}
    </p>

   </div>
  {{/if}}   card.description contains text with HTML tags